# Tkinter : Window not opening when incrementing value,

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm  making a BSOD simulator with a randomly progressing percentage.
What i'm trying to do is :

1. Make a variable called percentage and initialise it with a value of `0`
2. Make a label with the text `f"{percentage}% completed"`
3. Make a variable called percentageIsAHundred and initialise it with a value of `False`

Works good. Output : 0% completed

Now to add the random steps :

1. Make a loop as long as percentageIsAHundred is false
2. Change the value of percentageText to `f"{percentage}% completed"` (to update it)
3. We do a `win.after()` (I've tried sleep and threading- don't work) and put the values `1000`, and a function called steps
4. Check if the percentage value is above 100, If it returns true we set percentageText to `100% completed` (otherwise it might be 106% or 104%) and set percentageIsAHundred to true, breaking the loop.

In the steps function we:

1. Increment the percentage variable by a random value in between 0 and 20

Should work? Nope.

No windows open and no errors appear in console. Commenting out the code works and returns to normal.

I have seen that this behaviour occurs at the `steps()` function, Although I may be wrong.

```py
# Importing modules
from tkinter import *
import os
import random
import threading

# Initialising Tkinter window
win = Tk()

# Creating reboot function
def reboot(sec=50):
    os.system(f'echo "{sec} timer not confirmed"')


# Giving the window its iconic blue background.
win.config(bg="#0178d6")

# Making the window fullscreen
win.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

# Adding the emoticon ":("
emoticon = Label(win, text=":(", font="{Segoe UI} 100", bg="#0178d6", fg="#ffffff")
emoticon.place(x="50px", y="100px")

# Adding the text
text1 = Label(win, text="A problem has occurred and your PC needs to restart. We're just collecting some error information, then we'll restart for you.", font="{Segoe UI} 20", bg="#0178d6", fg="#ffffff")
text1.place(x="50px", y="259px")

# Adding the progress percentage
percentage = 0
percentageText = Label(win, text=f"{percentage}% complete", font="{Segoe UI} 20", bg="#0178d6", fg="#ffffff")
percentageText.place(x="50px", y="320px")
percentageIsAHundred = False

________________________________________________________

# This is the problematic code- Removing it seems to run the window normally but including it causes tkinter to not run with 0 errors  

def steps(percentage=percentage) :
    percentage = percentage + random.randint(1, 20)
win.after(1000, steps)
while percentageIsAHundred == False :
    percentageText.config(text=f"{percentage}% complete")
    if percentage >= 100 :
        percentageText.config(text="100% complete")
        percentageIsAHundred = True
________________________________________________________

# Setting the mainloop
win.mainloop()
```

! My title may not be right because I can't think clear right now. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `percentage` in `steps()` is *local* to that function.

If you want it to increase the value of the global percentage, you should mark it at such:

```
def steps():
    global percentage
    percentage += random.randint(1, 20)
    win.after(1000, steps)
    percentageText.config(text=f"{percentage}% complete")
    if percentage >= 100:
        percentageText.config(text="100% complete")
        win.quit()
```

Also note that as a rule you should be careful with `while` and `for` loops in event handlers and after functions. If they take too long, they will inhibit event processing.

Also, your while loop is not indented, so it in not part of `steps` but part of the main module. In this case, since your your `while` loop runs *before* the `mainloop`, it prevents the tkinter `mainloop` from starting and your window from appearing. :-)